# How to update version number of package.json file automatically

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have a requirement for upgrading the `package.json` version automatically through jenkins. We have the node project which will build through Jenkins, everything is fine but when we want to upgrade `version` in `package.json` everytime we need to manually make changes in package.json and then push to Jenkins through GitLab.

Is there any way to automate this step??

Here is Jenkinsfile

```
  pipeline {
  agent any
 stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
         checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'ID', url: 'https://gitlab.com/company/website.git']]])
             sh "pwd"
             sh "npm install"
             sh "npm run build"  
          }
       }
        stage('deploy') {
          steps {
                 sh "scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/build/* ubuntu@prod:/var/www/project/"
         }
       }       
     }      
   }
```

Here is package.json file

```
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.1.24",
  "description": "web application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://gitlab.com/",
  "private": true,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved with awk command line tool in linux

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

awk -F'["]' -v OFS='"'  '/"version":/{split($4,a,".");$4=a[1]+1"."a[2]"."a[3]+1};1' ./package.json > ./package2.json && mv ./package2.json ./package.json
```